# MongoDB - How do join between the two collections by getting only one document from the second collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using Mongo 3.4.24. I have two collections - **health**, **health_history**.

I keep health of the different nodes in the document in the health collection and during each snapshot I move the older documents to health_history

**health**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("61857adabe73638f9c8bca19"),
    "name": "Test",
    "snapshot_time": "2021-11-05 11:41:28",
    "status": "DOWN",
    "create_time": ISODate("2021-11-05T18:41:30.468Z")
}
```

**health_history** - which keeps the older documents from **health** collection

I want to find how long Test has been DOWN for by finding the last time when the status was UP.

The challenge is there are multiple documents for **Test** in health_history. I need to find the latest **create_time** from the document in **health_history** when it was **UP** and calculate the time difference (in minutes) with the document in **health** collection and create a new key **duration**

Something like

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("61857adabe73638f9c8bca19"),
    "name": "Test",
    "snapshot_time": "2021-11-05 11:41:28",
    "status": "DOWN",
    "create_time": ISODate("2021-11-05T18:41:30.468Z"),
    "duration": "30"

}
```

How do I do this in Mongo?

Comment: Can you provide an example of `health_history` collection?

Comment: It’s exactly the same as healthy. I archive documents from healthy to healthy _history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$lookup` health_history
2. `$match` to keep `status:"UP"` records only
3. `$sort` by `create_time` of the hist document
4. `$limit: 1` to get the last "UP" document
5. use `$subtract` to get the date difference as you are using Mongo 3.4. `$divide` the result by 60000(60s * 1000ms = 1 minute) to get the difference in minute interval

```js
db.health.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "name": "Test"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "health_history",
      "localField": "name",
      "foreignField": "name",
      "as": "hist"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$hist"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "hist.status": "UP"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "hist.create_time": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      duration: {
        "$divide": [
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$create_time",
              "$hist.create_time"
            ]
          },
          // 60s * 1000ms = 1 minute
          60000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BcMTN1ecIRC) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you, the solution worked.